# Recommendations for getting started with Azure Automation and Reporting

Tags: azure, powershell

I am planning to do some work with Azure Virtual Machines this summer, a topic I am so far completely unfamiliar with. The goal is to write a program that can automate reporting and feedback coming from the VMs. For my powershell/Azure devs in the house, do you have any recommended tutorials/guides that will bring me up to speed on the tech quickly? The official Microsoft guides look promising... Any alternatives you would recommend?

Comment: What exactly do you want to automate? Microsoft supports a few options to automate work with Virtual Machines. Here is documentation and examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/infrastructure-automation

Comment: Microsoft docs are definitely your best bet. Find what information you need in the reporting, look for a PowerShell command that returns that data and read the docs i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **PowerShell**, you can use the [PowerShell Workflow Runbook to automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual) your scripts.

- Create a run book
- Test and Run a run book.
- Automate/Schedule your run book.

Refer [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-powershell-to-monitor-your-azure-machine/) PowerShell Scripts to monitor azure VM.

You can use [Python runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-python-3) also to get the VM details.